# Couchbase replication and google maps

Tags: android, json, google-maps, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm trying to replicate a couchbase database and use the json formatted data on a google map in an Android activity.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {

final String dbname = "myapp";
private Manager manager;
private Database database;

private static final String SYNC_URL = "http://url/myapp/";
private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";
GoogleMap googleMap;
private String docId = "123";
Poi poi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Get the SupportMapFragment and request notification
    // when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    createManager();
    createCouchdb();
    createDocument(database);

    Document retrievedDocument = retrieveDocument(docId);
    updateDocument(retrievedDocument);

    replication();

    // retrievePoi(manager, database, docId);
    retrievePoi(database, docId);
}

public void createManager() {
    try {
        manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(getApplicationContext()), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
        Log.w("myApp", "manager created");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("myApp", "manager error");
        return;
    }
}

public void createCouchdb() {
    try {
        database = manager.getDatabase(dbname);
        Log.w("myApp", "database created");
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        Log.w("myApp", "database error");
        return;
    }
}

public void replication() {

    // Create replicators to push & pull changes to & from Sync Gateway.
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(SYNC_URL);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Set up a channel-filtered pull replication that will pull only
    // docs in the "sales" channel from the Sync Gateway:
    database.createPullReplication(url);
    List<String> channels = new ArrayList<String>();
    channels.add("public");
    Replication pull = database.createPullReplication(url);
    pull.setChannels(channels);

    Replication push = database.createPushReplication(url);
    push.setContinuous(true);
    pull.setContinuous(true);

    // Start replicators
    push.start();
    pull.start();

}

private String createDocument(Database database) {
    // Create a new document and add data
    Document document = database.createDocument();
    String documentId = document.getId();

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("name", "Big Party");
    map.put("location", "My House");
    try {
        // Save the properties to the document
        document.putProperties(map);
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error putting", e);
    }
    return documentId;
}

public Document retrieveDocument(String docId) {
    Document retrievedDocument = database.getDocument(docId);
    // display the retrieved document
    Log.d(TAG, "retrievedDocument=" + String.valueOf(retrievedDocument.getProperties()));
    return retrievedDocument;
}


public void updateDocument(Document doc) {
    Map<String, Object> updatedProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    updatedProperties.putAll(doc.getProperties());
    updatedProperties.put ("message", "We're having a heat wave!");
    updatedProperties.put ("temperature", "95");

    try {
        doc.putProperties(updatedProperties);
        Log.w("myApp", "document updated");
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        Log.w("myApp", "document update error");
    }
}



private Poi retrievePoi(Database database, String docId) {
    Object poiObj = null;
    Document retrievedDocument = database.getDocument(docId);
    Poi p1=null;
    try{
     p1 =parseDocPoi(retrievedDocument);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("ex",e.getMessage());
    }
    // Retrieve the document by id
   return p1;
}

private Poi parseDocPoi(Document d ) {
    Object poiObj;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    poiObj = d.getProperties().get("poi");
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(poiObj, Map.class); //Convert the object to json string using Gson
    Poi poi = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Poi.class); //convert the json string to Poi object
//        Log.i("getPoiFromDocument", "jsonString>>>" + jsonString);
////        Log.i("getPoiFromDocument", "poi>>>" + poi.getTitle());
//        Log.i("getPoiFromDocument", "longitude>>>" + poi.getLongitude());
//        Log.i("getPoiFromDocument", "latitude>>>" + poi.getLatitude());
//        Log.i("getPoiFromDocument", "category>>>" + poi.getCategory());
//        Log.i("getPoiFromDocument", "order>>>" + poi.getOrder());

    return poi;
}


private List<Poi> retrieveAllPois(Database database, String channel) {
    List<Poi> listOfPois = null;


    // Let's find the documents that have conflicts so we can resolve them:
    Query query = database.createAllDocumentsQuery();
    query.setAllDocsMode(Query.AllDocsMode.ALL_DOCS);
    QueryEnumerator result = null;
    try {
        result = query.run();
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = result; it.hasNext(); ) {

        QueryRow row = it.next();
        Poi p=null;
       // p = parseDocPoi(row.getDocument());
        Log.i("MYAPP - categ", row.getDocument().getId().toString());

        Log.i("MYAPP - categ", p.getCategory());
        listOfPois.add(p);
            //beginConflictResolution(row.getDocument());
    }

    return listOfPois;
}




    @Override
    public void onMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap){
        List<Poi> listPois = null;
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
        // and move the map's camera to the same location.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney"));

        LatLng athens = new LatLng(37.97945, 23.71622);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(athens)
                .title("Athens"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(athens));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f));

        ArrayList<Poi> mPoi = new ArrayList<Poi>();
        mPoi.add(new Poi("city", 21.22, 22.33, "category1", "order1"));
        mPoi.add(new Poi("city", 22.33, 22.33, "category2", "order2"));

        listPois = retrieveAllPois(database,"todo channel");
        for (Poi p  : listPois) {
            Log.i("test",p.getTitle());
        }
        mPoi.addAll(listPois);
  //            for (int i = 0; i < mPoi.size(); i++) {
  //              Poi p1 =   retrievePoi(database, "poi:FCEC0C58-9520-4A18-A66A-62A835745051");
  //
  //            }
  //            for (Poi p  : listPois) {
  //               mPoi.add(p.getTitle(),p.getLatitude(), p.getLongitude(), p.getCategory(), p.getOrder()));
  //                Log.i("test",p.getTitle());
  //                //Log.i("test",(String)p.getLongitude());
  //
  //
  ////                final LatLng position = new LatLng(p.getLatitude(), p.getLongitude());
  ////                Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
  ////                        .position(position)
  ////                        .snippet(position + " is cool")
  ////                );
 ////                googleMap.addMarker((new 
  MarkerOptions().position(position)
 ////                        .title("position")));
 //            }

    }

}
```

I have read the documentation and some examples but still can't find a way to connect the replicated database with the Map. Any ideas will be appreciated!! Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I'm confused about what you're expecting here.  The first section of code creates, updates, then deletes a document.  So your database is empty, unless you are adding a document somewhere else.  Even if you did have something in the database, I don't see where in the code you connect a document with your Google map instance.  Can you say more about what you're expecting and what's going wrong?

Comment: I just updated the code, what about now?

Comment: Looks better, but I still see at least a couple of problems.  In onMapReady, you're getting a list of Pois, but the don't seem to do anything with them.  You're iterating over documents in the query, but you set poi to null and add that, so you'll just have a bunch of nulls in your list.  I think there are other problems, too.  Stackoverflow isn't meant for extended discussions of code like this.  I'd suggest going back and rereading the documentation, build up your app a step at a time, and post questions about specific problems.